# Why am I receiving a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Connections#index error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to call localhost:3000/connections so I can see if I have set up connections correctly in my app.

When I do, I receive an error message saying:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Connections#index
Showing c:/Users/Doesha/desktop/connections/app/views/connections/index.html.erb where line #14 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: connections: SELECT "connections".* FROM "connections"
```

Here's my index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Connections</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @connections.each do |connection| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= connection.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', connection %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_connection_path(connection) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', connection, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Connection', new_connection_path %>
```

Here's my connections_controller.rb:

```
class ConnectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_connection, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @connections = Connection.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @connection = Connect.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @connection = Connection.new(connection_params)

      if @connection.save
        redirect_to @connection, notice: 'Connection was successfully created.' 
      else
        render action :new
      end
    end


  def update
      if @connection.update(connection_params)
        redirect_to @connection, notice: 'Connection was successfully updated.' 
      else
        render action :edit 
      end
    end

  def destroy
    @connection.destroy
      redirect_to connections_url, notice: 'Connection was successfully destroyed.' 
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_connection
      @connection = Connection.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def connection_params
      params.require(:connection).permit(:description)
    end
end
```

Anyone know what the problem might be?  Thanks!

Comment: The table doesn't exist, you need to run rake db:create, rake db:migrate etc

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite error message is saying that no connections table exists.

You probably need to run `rake db:migrate` in the terminal window to create the necessary table. After you restart the server, the action should work fine.